# How to filter out data while adding new rules

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I am trying to create a simple filter system but having issues.

**The situation:**

The user clicks on the filter option and presses "Apply" after selecting the filter choice:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9XBl.jpg

Instead of the search results getting smaller filtering out the information, it just enlarges and shows results of all filter options selected.

**What I want:**

If I choose color Royal, the array should shrink and only show those results. Then if I choose city "Toronto", the results should shrink further narrowing it down to results that fit all parameters.

The globalFilterList holds in the data collected after choosing your filter type.

```
let globalFilterList = {
    color: [],
    style: {
       front: [],
       back: []
    },
    date: [],
    location: [],
    status: []
};

 
function gatherDataResults(){
    $(newData).each(function(){
          if( 
             $(this)[0]["color"] == globalFilterList["color"][0]
             || $(this)[0]["city"] == globalFilterList["location"][0]
             || $(this)[0]["province"] == globalFilterList["location"][1]
             || $(this)[0]["status"] == globalFilterList["status"][0])
          {
            
          // Clear original data first before appending new data
          $('.ordersPageTable').html('');
          $('.ordersPageTable').append(`
          <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox"/></th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Date Issued</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th><button class="printBatchBtn">Print Batch <img src="images/orders/printerIcon.svg" width="21"/></button></th>
          </tr>`);
            
          /* Update the search results to reflect what we searched for */
          tableData += `
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
            <td>${$(this)[0]["sku"]} <span>${$(this)[0]["first_name"]} ${$(this)[0]["last_name"]}</span></td>
            <td>${$(this)[0]["Order_Date"]}</span></td>
            <td>${$(this)[0]["shipment_status"]}<span>${currentStatus[$(this)[0]["shipment_status"]]}</span></td>
            <td class="viewPrintOrder"><button class="viewBtn" data-customerID='${$(this)[0]["customer_id"]}'>View</button><button class="printBtn" data-customerID='${$(this)[0]["customer_id"]}'>Print</button></td>
          </tr>`;
            
            $('.ordersPageTable').append(tableData);
        }
   })
}
```

I am simply calling this function every time the user clicks "Apply Filter".

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit confused, shouldn't there be an array of data and you use something like data.filter() on it? and maybe add conditions with && inside the filter or loop on multiple filters?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'm leaning towards that but I have no clue how to put it into code. I realized I need to filter out the data but unsure how to incorporate it. The each loop doesn't seem like the best way.

Comment: Is this jQuery you're using? I'm more used to Vanilla JS so I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Yes, Jquery but I am fine with both. Whichever has the ideal solution.

Comment: I still couldn't fully wrap my head around it, however I think if you use multi stage filtering using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it may solve the issue, and I would be happy to try to work on the code if you provide a jsfiddle for example.

Comment: Pretty difficult to do that as a lot of the data is from php, and other dynamic events. It's a large application.

Comment: Maybe just provide a sample data array and we can work on that, I just need the structure of the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247149/discussion-between-jordan-brown-and-bahax).